# How does one read this function: $f:R\to R:x\to x^2$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I know what each part of this expression means but how is it supposed to be read out? $$f:R\to R:x\to x^2$$

My attempt would be something like: f is the function of x mapping x on to x squared where the domain is the set of real numbers and the codomain is the set of real numbers.

This seems far too wordy. What is the standard way of reading the above expression?

Comment: Could you write that without using any symbols or mathematical operators? Just using English words.

Comment: the function f from Real numbers to real numbers sends every x to x squared

Comment: The English statement is correct, but the notation for the same is usually written as $$ f: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R} \\ ~~~~~~x \longmapsto x^2$$

Comment: I would read this (aloud) as "$f$ from $R$ to $R$ mapping $x$ to $x$ squared".

Comment: In french the usual saying is "une fonction de R dans R qui a x associe x^2", this translates to : "a function from R to R which to x associates x^2" but I'm not sure the `which to`sounds that good in english. But the word mapping used by Magdiragdag seems overkill to me in a context where we are not talking about bijections and co.

Comment: Merci zwim, votre comment est utile.